# How can I group the numbers based on the source and destination?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There are N - pair of numbers given in the problem, objective is to find the number of groups can be found using the relation.

Test case 1:

```
5
2 3
4 5
1 4
6 7
5 6
```

The grouping will look like

```
2->3
1->4->5->6->7
```

Required Output

```
The number of groups is 2
```

Test case 2:

```
6
2 4
3 1
6 5
7 6
9 8
22 32
```

The grouping will look like

```
2->4
3->1
7->6->5
9->8
22->32
```

Required output

```
The number of groups is 5
```

I hope the question is clear to you guys, I don't know where to start or how to google it and find the relevant article, If you know any concepts to solve this question, kindly be gentle in the comments, I am a noob in dsa :)

Comment: Hi! Most relevant keyword is: [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)). Another keyword that can be useful is: [union-find or disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the ***connected components*** in a graph.

A simple algorithm:

```
* First, build a structure that makes it easy and fast to get the direct neighbours of a given node.

* Initialise a set Unvisited, originally containing all nodes.

* Loop until Unvisited is empty:
    * remove a node u from Unvisited
    * initialise a Queue, originally containing u
    * initialise a new Connected_Component, originally empty
    * Loop until Queue is empty:
        * remove a node v from the Queue
        * add v to Connected_Component
        * remove all Unvisited neighbours of v from Unvisited and add them to the Queue
```

Relevant references:

- [Connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory));
- [Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(data_structure)); "queue" is generally understood to mean "first-in first-out", but in this particular case the order doesn't matter.
- [Adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), a structure representing a graph by giving the list of neighbours of every node.